# Почему долго джойнит записи

Tags: sql, postgresql

В запросе `uid` - это md5 в текстовом формате.

Должно объединится и загрузиться около миллиона записей.

Почему это так долго работает?

```
SELECT 
  public."Call".uid,
  public."Call".num,
  public."Call".year_num,
  public."Call".ssmp,
  public."Call".type,
  public."Call".priority,
  public."Call".sector,
  public."Call".substation,
  public."Call".console,
  public."CallAddress".place,
  public."CallAddress".district,
  public."CallAddress".city,
  public."CallAddress".street,
  public."CallAddress".house,
  public."CallAddress".corps,
  public."CallAddress".flat,
  public."CallAddress".entrance,
  public."CallAddress".entrance_code,
  public."CallAddress".add_info,
  public."CallAddress".floor,
  public."CallTime".accept,
  public."CallTime".given,
  public."CallTime".departure,
  public."CallTime".arrival,
  public."CallTime".to_home,
  public."CallTime".in_home,
  public."CallTime".duration,
  public."CallTime".mileage,
  public."CallResult".result,
  public."CallResult".ds_type,
  public."CallResult".main_ds,
  public."CallResult".add_ds,
  public."CallResult".alcohol,
  public."CallResult".add_info,
  public."CallReasonInfo".reason,
  public."CallReasonInfo".reason_info,
  public."CallReasonInfo".who_call,
  public."CallReasonInfo".phone,
  public."CallReasonInfo".surname,
  public."CallReasonInfo".name,
  public."CallReasonInfo".patronymic,
  public."CallReasonInfo".age,
  public."CallReasonInfo".sex,
  public."CallReasonInfo".profile,
  public."CallCrew".call_profile,
  public."CallCrew".crew,
  public."CallCrew".crew_profile,
  public."CallCrew".car,
  public."CallCrew".radio,
  public."CallCrew".head_id,
  public."CallCrew".assist1,
  public."CallCrew".assist2,
  public."CallCrew".driver,
  public."CallCrew".substation,
  public."CallCrew".substation_control,
  public."CallCrew".accept,
  public."CallCrew".appoint,
  public."CallCrew".transfer,
  public."CallCrew".close,
  public."CallCrew".head_doctor,
  public."CallCrew".head_dispatcher,
  public."CallCrew".given,
  public."CallCrew".calls,
  public."CallCrew".prdl,
  public."CallCrew".daily,
  public."CallMedicine".medicine,
  public."CallMedicine".quantity,
  public."Hospitalization".sector,
  public."Hospitalization".area,
  public."Hospitalization".hospital,
  public."Hospitalization".to_hospital,
  public."Hospitalization".in_hospital,
  public."Hospitalization".ds,
  public."Hospitalization".ds_compare,
  public."Hospitalization".exp_mark,
  public."Patient".surname,
  public."Patient".name,
  public."Patient".patronymic,
  public."Patient".birthdate,
  public."Patient".age,
  public."Patient".sex,
  public."Patient".work,
  public."PatientContact".district,
  public."PatientContact".city,
  public."PatientContact".street,
  public."PatientContact".house,
  public."PatientContact".corps,
  public."PatientContact".flat,
  public."PatientContact".phone,
  public."PatientContact".hospital,
  public."PatientDoc".doc_type,
  public."PatientDoc".doc_ser_num,
  public."PatientDoc".doc_who,
  public."PatientDoc".doc_date,
  public."PatientDoc".polis_type,
  public."PatientDoc".polis_ser_num,
  public."PatientDoc".polis_date,
  public."PatientDoc".smo,
  public."PatientDoc".snils
  FROM
  public."Call"
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."CallAddress" ON (public."Call".uid = public."CallAddress".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."CallCrew" ON (public."Call".uid = public."CallCrew".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."CallMedicine" ON (public."Call".uid = public."CallMedicine".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."CallReasonInfo" ON (public."Call".uid = public."CallReasonInfo".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."CallResult" ON (public."Call".uid = public."CallResult".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."CallTime" ON (public."Call".uid = public."CallTime".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."Hospitalization" ON (public."Call".uid = public."Hospitalization".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."Patient" ON (public."Call".uid = public."Patient".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."PatientContact" ON (public."Call".uid = public."PatientContact".uid)
  FULL OUTER JOIN public."PatientDoc" ON (public."Call".uid = public."PatientDoc".uid)
  where  public."Call".ssmp::INTEGER=1
```

Comment: Вполне возможно что у вас нету каких-то индексов...

Comment: Долго - это сколько? Секунда? минута? час?

Comment: *Должно объединится и загрузиться около миллиона записей.* Ну так пока этот лям записей закэшится на диск (фиг они поместились в памяти, небось)...

Comment: А что в таблицах ? на один uid в одной таблице сколько приходится записей в других ? т.е. там связь многие ко многим или один к одному. Если один к одному, зачем так много таблиц. И куда этот миллион должен загрузиться, зачем там, куда это грузится весь миллион сразу. Обычно для редактирования представляется одновременно лишь небольшая часть. И почему именно FULL OUTER JOIN у всех таблиц, неужели среди этих таблиц нет ни одной, где есть записи с данным uid всегда ? Если такой таблицы нет, очевидно структуру БД надо менять ... А если есть, то менять виды join ...

Comment: Попробуйте ещё сначала отфильровать по `where  public."Call".ssmp::INTEGER=1`, а потом приджоинить получившийся результат ко всем остальным таблицам. В случае, когда фильтрация достаточно много строк скипает, может стать легче.

Comment: И кстати, зачем в условии приводится тим ssmp, оно другого типа ? приведение типа колонки делает невозможным использование индекса, даже если он есть

Comment: Какие индексы к текстовому полю varchar использовать в нем md5 лежит?Грузится минут 10 все ..Тут главная таблица вызовов Call все отстальные таблицы - это связанные данные с вызовом , однозначно эти данные связанны по md5 .

Comment: ssmp это некий пункт с конторым связанны вызовы и таких много , тут пример с выгрузкой по первому

Comment: если в call всегда что то есть, то join можно менять на LEFT, это если в остальных таблицах наличие записей не гарантируется, думаю это должно понравится оптимизатору, от FULL у него наверняка едет крыша. И вы не сказали что там с количеством записей, уникален ли uid в остальных таблицах или где то может быть несколько записей с одним uid (а тогда все записи перемножаться и там где был миллион строк станут триллионы)

Comment: во всех таблицах uid уникален

Comment: А что вы потом с этим миллионом делаете, просто куда то выгружаете как есть ? И зачем все таки `::INTEGER` там поле другого типа и вы его меняете ? попробуйте убрать это приведение типа

Comment: К этой выборке потом необходимо делать еще очень много разных выборок ,  чтобы узнать например сколько беременных было с такого числа по такое-то в этом пункте , с каким они диагнозом были и тд.тп, узнать процент от того то от первоначальной выборки и всякие подобные запросы к первоначальной выборке

Comment: там тип Varchar

Comment: Изначально ssmp может быть еще больше(массив) и за указанный период

Comment: получается вы используете БД исключительно для хранения данных. Причем странного хранения. вы сначала разбрасываете данные относящиеся к одному и тому же по диску, как можно дальше, а потом пробуете это все собрать обратно в одну запись, при этом головкам диска приходится постоянно метаться от одной таблицы к другой. В случае с двумя таблицами результат уже получался бы в полтора раза дольше, чем если бы данные физически лежали рядом. с 10 таблицами, страшно представить. т.е. положив данные, которые связаны один к одному в разные таблицы вы сделали работу с ними невозможной

Comment: И в любом случае если у вас данные лежат в БД, то считать вот те проценты за интервал дат и т.п. надо в самой БД, что бы на выходе было только небольшое кол-во результирующих записей. Сейчас вы используете автомобильный завод с самым современным оборудованием для хранения заготовок, а автомобили выпускаете отдельно, рядом в гараже, в ручную

Comment: И да, теперь я понимаю зачем postgesql сжирает всю память в системе, какой бы вы выбрали алгоритм слияния 10 массивов данных, разбросанных по диску ? Единственный рабочий способ, это поднять с диска как можно больше данных, а потом объединять их в оперативке, что бы уменьшить необходимое перемещение головок диска

Comment: Т.е. я хочу сказать, что такая структура как сейчас может жить, но при условии, что в запросах, которые должны получить некие величины не используются все 10 таблиц, а только те, что реально необходимы для конкретных параметров. Если вам надо получить статистику по какому то диагнозу, то в таком запросе вряд ли важны адреса пациентов. И кстати я на понимаю одного в структуре, если все привязано к звонкам и один пациент обращался 3 раза, то ведь от этого его не стало трое, он должен оставаться в БД один ...

Comment: И когда информация будет в БД в таком виде, как она в реальном мире, т.е. пациентов не будет много, если это один реальный человек, то тогда SQL будет гораздо лучше справляться с работой